# Как сделать простое проксирование через docker в nginx

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

Никак не могу разобраться как сделать прокси через `nginx`. Мне нужно перенаправить всех кто заходит на урл

`http://мой-ip`

на

`http://мой-ip:3000`

Мой `nginx.conf` файл

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ip:3000/;
    }
}
```

Использую docker-compose.

```
version: "3"

networks:
  dbnet:

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf.prod:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    networks:
      - dbnet
```

Есть 4 папок в корне проекта и в одном из них папка `nginx` с  файлом `nginx.conf`

Что не так?

**EDIT**

*ip это -> ip адрес дроплета на DigitalOcean*

Никакой ошибки нет, `nginx` запускается, все контейнеры поднимаются и если перейти на страницу `http://мой-ip`, то показывается страница приветствие `nginx`-a.

Comment: 1. `proxy_pass http://ip:3000/` - тут ip случаем не локалхост или 127.0.0.1? 2. Какая ошибка? Вообще контейнер поднимается? Что говорит docker ps?

Comment: @TotalPusher дополнил ответ.

Comment: `listen 80 default_server;`. Не забудьте перезапустить nginx. Или `nginx -s reload`

Comment: @TotalPusher благодарю! Вечером проверю и отвечу вам.

Comment: а зачем вам запускать nginx в docker? установите его прямо на машину

Comment: @Demon__ location с проксированием выглядить нормально. Если решение @TotalPusher не поможет, то приложите к вопросу ваш полный конфиг nginx. Команда ```nginx -T``` его вам выведет.

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov хорошо, благодарю. Вечером отпишусь.

Comment: @TotalPusher заработало, спасибо. Напишите ответ, приму

Comment: Если вам НЕ нужны различные варианты обработки входящего трафика, можно сделать даже еще проще - [проктировать TCP трафик](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/). `server { listen 80 default_server; proxy_pass http://ip:3000/; }`.

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо и не забываем что - мы все Ниган!